# Overlapping of dynamic and static routes in next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I created a nextJS application and using its routing system there. Now I have created a dynamic route to catch a URL like `{base_url}/{username}/{post-slug}`. But it is also capturing `{base_url}/post/create` which I want to be rendered on different page.
So is there anything available in nextJS route to match a URL absolutely? Like, exact in react router? Or do I have to redirect user from getInitialProps function in nextJS?

Comment: Check the document content using the keyword `Regular expression` may help

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I can't find any reference for regexp in the routing documentation of the next js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created sample [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-lake-j20v0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for this question.

It works without Regular Expression. Always the specific route (`post/create`) has the priority.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. This is not a direct anwer but, I think the structure of your user route should be `{base_url}/user/{username}/{post-slug}`. This matches `http://yourhostname/user/{username}/{post-slug}` and doesn't conflict the post route.